# After passing a string to my Activity, trying to get it in a fragment results in an empty string

Tags: android, string, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I pass a String via intent like this:

```
val intent = Intent(this, RegistrationActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("mobile", user.mobile)
        startActivity(intent)
```

Then I successfully receive this in my RegistrationActivity.

```
private var mobile : String? = ""
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration_layout)

    val intent = this.intent
    val extras = intent.extras
    mobile = extras?.getString("mobile")
    }

fun getMobile(): String {
    return mobile!!
}
```

but then when I call getMobile() in a fragment that lives in the RegistrationActivity, all I get is an empty string:

```
val activity = RegistrationActivity()
val mobile = activity.getMobile()
```

Comment: how do you call your fragment from RegistrationActivity?

Comment: I use a NavHostFragment

Comment: `RegistrationActivity()` why are you instantiating a new instance of Activity by hand? You should NEVER do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Don't** create an instance of `activity` like that, use `startActivity()` to navigate to `activity`, it will create an instance of it. check  [Activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#alc)

since you created an instance of the `activity` in the wrong way, the `onCreate()` won't call and `mobile` will be the initial value.

here is an example of how you can access `activity` from `fragment`:

```kotlin
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val mobile = (activity as? RegistrationActivity)?.getMobile()
}
```